# Save custom Prompt string in command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, prompt

I've come to like starting all my sessions with a

```
prompt $D$H$H$H$H$H$H$H$H$H $T$H$H$H $P $_
```

Is there a way to just save it so it does it itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom prompt which keeps between sessions like this:

Add an "User Environment Variables" named "Prompt".

It's explained on [this website](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Custom-Windows-Command-Prompt)